# Add a Custom Control reference in VS10

Tags: visual-studio-2010, custom-controls

I recently created my first custom control. I attempted to add it in a separate project I have constructed.

I recieve this error:
  The type 'System.Windows.Controls.Control' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly

Here are the steps I took to add the control.

1. Add the Custom Control as a Reference in project
2. Add the attribute   xmlns:MyNamespace="clr-namespace:CustomControls;assembly=CustomControls" to the root element of the markup file where it is being used
3. Rebuild the Controller and the project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need a reference to `PresentationFramework.dll`

Comment: in the original control, or in the project?

Comment: disregard the above comment. Adding it now. Will let you know how it goes.

Comment: I also needed to add System.Xaml and PresentationCore